# Finding 2D array index from the biggest and smallest number randomed in the 2D array

Tags: java

so im just trying to fool around the 2D array, and im curious about one thing

I made a code to return the index of the biggest and smallest number randomed in the 2d array, i tried on *10, and it works perfectly, but when i try to times it 100, the max number works, but the min number isnt working, i keep looking back and forth and just cant find it, here is my code, i actually asked this in the answer section on my last question but it got deleted so i have to ask in a question again, im sorry i just started out a few days ago, and there are so much to ask

for the min number
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRXeu.png)

for the max number
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPrbm.png)

```
int[][] mdArray = new int[5][5];
int i =0;
int j =0;
int min = 0;

for(i=0; i<mdArray.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<mdArray[i].length; j++) {
        mdArray[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.print(mdArray[i][j] + " ");

        if(min>mdArray[i][j])
        {
            min= mdArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

System.out.println("");
for(i=0; i<mdArray.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<mdArray[i].length; j++){
        if(mdArray[i][j] == min) {
            System.out.println("["+i+"]"+"["+j+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you give more details about your code, there is no min variable declared. I am assuming the max variable was supposed to be named min?

Comment: ahh yes, i didnt make the variable for min, i was just playing with the operator in 

if(min>mdArray[i][j])
        {
            min= mdArray[i][j];
        }

sorry my bad, i only made 1 variable , so let me just edit it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't find `min` because `min` is starting at 0, which means it is already lower than any of your random numbers.

`Min` needs to start at 100, `max` needs to start at 0.

```
int[][] mdArray = new int[5][5];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int min = 100;

for(i = 0; i < mdArray.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < mdArray[i].length; j++) {
        mdArray[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.print(mdArray[i][j] + " ");

        if(min>mdArray[i][j])
        {
            min= mdArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

System.out.println("");
for(i = 0; i < mdArray.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < mdArray[i].length; j++){
        if(mdArray[i][j] == min) {
            System.out.println("["+i+"]"+"["+j+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you initialize `min` with zero, and nothing in the array is lower than zero. Try to initialize it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.